# How to paint a text control on mouse hover?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having troubles painting my static text controls. I have done some reading on this matter, and I have also tried some codes, but none of them worked. The closest that I managed to get was until the text control detects my mouse hover event. For this, I use control subclassing. However, I don't know what I can do to paint the text controls upon mouse hover.

My questions are:

1. I am confused whether to place the code responsible for painting the text control either in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` or `WM_MOUSEHOVER` in the subclass. The reason is because in the `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, I set it so that when the rectangle area of the text control detects the cursor, painting should happen. At the same time, I feel weird because shouldn't that particular role already be done by `WM_MOUSEHOVER`?
2. I really need help on how I could highlight the text control when the mouse is hovered.

```cpp
// global text control handler
HWND txtHwnd; //somewhere in the global area of codes

//class for mouse event tracking
class MouseTrackEvents
{
    bool m_bMouseTracking;

public:
    MouseTrackEvents() : m_bMouseTracking(false) {}

    void OnMouseMove(HWND hwnd)
    {
        if (!m_bMouseTracking)
        {
            // Enable mouse tracking.
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
            tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
            tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
            tme.dwHoverTime = 100; //0.1s
            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            m_bMouseTracking = true;
        }
    }
    void Reset(HWND hwnd)
    {
        m_bMouseTracking = false;
    }
};

//subclass proc for text control
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerTxtProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    //local mouse track object
    MouseTrackEvents mouseTrack;

    const int numOfMsg = 4;
    int myMsgBox[numOfMsg]; //limit to only 4

    HBRUSH hbrBkgndA = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));

    //just want to print what wparam is..
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    wchar_t wParamHI[1000];
    wchar_t wParamLO[1000];

    //for painting
    COLORREF hbrHighlight;
    //HBRUSH hbrHighlight;
    HDC txtHDC;
    RECT txtRect;

    POINT txtPt;
    RECT txtRt;

    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            //testing purposes
            myMsgBox[0] = MessageBox(nullptr, L"Yessir!", L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            mouseTrack.OnMouseMove(hWnd); //activate mouse tracking
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &txtRt); //see what value lies within

            GetCursorPos(&txtPt);

            if (PtInRect(&txtRt, txtPt)) {
                //to check whether cursor is in text rect or not
                MessageBox(nullptr, L"Okea..nice..!", L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

                //i dont know what to do here
                //i was thinking that painting should be placed here...
                //HBRUSH hbrBkgndEdit = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100, 100, 255));
                
            }
            else {
                //to check whether cursor is in text rect or not
                MessageBox(nullptr, L"Oh noooo!", L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }

            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEHOVER: {
            //do something when txt ctrl is hovered
            //to test whether wm_mousehover works, and the text control is mouse hovered
            //myMsgBox[1] = MessageBox(nullptr, L"Yahooooo!", L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            OutputDebugString(L"--------------This text control is being hovered---------------\n");

            //testing painting when hovered
            //plan is to send message to hChild to manage the painting since it is the parent window
            //HDC theHDC = (HDC)wParam;
            //SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, (WPARAM)theHDC, (LPARAM)txtHwnd);

            //SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, (WPARAM)theHDC, lParam);

            //for painting
            //hbrHighlight = (COLORREF)(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
            //HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            ////SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            //SetBkColor(hdcStatic, hbrHighlight);

            //for painting II
            //HDC txtCtrlMe = (HDC)wParam;


            //SetTextColor(txtCtrl, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            //SetBkColor(txtCtrlMe, RGB(0, 255, 0));

            //SendMessage(hChild, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, (WPARAM)txtCtrlMe, (LPARAM)txtHwnd);

            //DeleteBrush(hbrBkgndA);

            mouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
            //return (INT_PTR)hbrHighlight;

            //mouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
            break;
            //return TRUE;
        }

        //case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        //{
        //  HDC txtCtrlMe = (HDC)wParam;

        //  //SetTextColor(txtCtrl, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        //  SetBkColor(txtCtrlMe, RGB(0, 255, 0));

        //  if (hbrBkgndA == NULL)
        //  {
        //      hbrBkgndA = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)); //eqivalent to delete brush objet
        //  }
        //  return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgndA;
        //  //break;
        //}

        //painting
        /*
            SendMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
            SendMessage(hChild, WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, (WPARAM)txtCtrlMe, (LPARAM)txtHwnd);
        */

        //you can just ignore this, this is just for me to see whats inside wParam of the subclass
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

            int HI = swprintf_s(wParamHI, 1000, L"wParamHI: %d", wmEvent);
            MessageBox(nullptr, wParamHI, L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

            int LO = swprintf_s(wParamLO, 1000, L"wParamLO: %d", wmId);
            MessageBox(nullptr, wParamLO, L":D", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

//child window proc, which contains the static text control
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        //...some other codes...

        txtHwnd = CreateWindow(L"Static", L"Hello World!", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY, 100, 100, 120, 15, hChild, (HMENU)testingTxtID, nullptr, nullptr);

        //control subclassing
        //a.k.a attaching subclass proc to the static text control
        SetWindowSubclass(txtHwnd, OwnerTxtProc, 0, 0);

        //...some other codes...

        default: {
           return DefWindowProc(hChild, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Please ignore the codes I commented out in `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and also `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` inside `OwnerTxtProc(...)`. They are just codes that I used to try to paint the text control, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All painting operations for your control should be only inside of a `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler, or even a `WM_PAINT` handler.

To trigger a repaint of the control, simply invalidate the control's client area using `InvalidateRect()`.

If you want to change the painting conditions, store the relevant information in variables that the painting code uses, and then update those variables before invalidating the control.

Try something like this:

```cpp
HWND txtHwnd;
bool bMouseTracking = false;
COLORREF bkgndColor = ...; // whatever you want...
COLORREF txtColor = ...; // whatever you want...
HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = nullptr;

const UINT APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC = WM_APP + 1;

LRESULT CALLBACK StaticTxtProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, StaticTxtProc, uIdSubclass);
            if (hbrBkgnd) {
                DeleteBrush(hbrBkgnd);
                hbrBkgnd = NULL;
            }
            bMouseTracking = false;
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            if (!bMouseTracking) {
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = {};
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
                tme.hwndTrack = hWnd;
                tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
                tme.dwHoverTime = 100; //0.1s
                bMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            }

            RECT txtRt;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &txtRt);

            POINT txtPt;
            GetCursorPos(&txtPt);

            if (PtInRect(&txtRt, txtPt)) {
                bkgndColor = ...; // whatever you want...
                txtColor = ...; // whatever you want...
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            }

            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEHOVER: {
            mMouseTracking = false;
            bkgndColor = ...; // whatever you want...
            txtColor = ...; // whatever you want...
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }

        case APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
            HDC hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);

            SetTextColor(hdc, txtColor);
            SetBkColor(hdc, bkgndColor);

            if (hbrBkgnd)
                DeleteBrush(hbrBkgnd);
            hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(bkgndColor);

            return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(bkgndColor);
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            // ...
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            bkgndColor = ...; // whatever you want...
            txtColor = ...; // whatever you want...

            txtHwnd = CreateWindow(L"Static", L"Hello World!", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY, 100, 100, 120, 15, hChild, (HMENU)testingTxtID, nullptr, nullptr);
            SetWindowSubclass(txtHwnd, StaticTxtProc, 0, 0);

            break;
        }

        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
            return SendMessage(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam), APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC, wParam, 0);
        }

        //...some other codes...

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hChild, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So...is the subclassing actually necessary for the text control? Or...should I place all the codes in the parent window of the text control?

Comment: @EliasaphWan `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is sent to the control's parent window, so your subclass would never see it. `WM_PAINT` is sent to the control, so your subclass would see that.

Comment: I remembered doing something inside WM_PAINT of the control subclass. There was no text output. So, I had to manually "TextOut" the text for the control. Are there any ways to not let WM_PAINT to remove the text I created at the CreateWindow calling for the control? Or am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: If you handle `WM_PAINT`, you are responsible for painting the entire control yourself. Otherwise, pass it to the default handler to get the default painting, and then draw on top of it as needed.

Comment: I am so sorry but by "then draw on top of it as needed", are the codes put into some other messages like the WM_PAINT or is this something I'm guessing about subclassing? I am so blurred right now and I really need help.

Comment: I'm referring to subclassing the control to receive the `WM_PAINT` message, and then having your `WM_PAINT` handler pass it to `DefWindowProc()` first for default drawing, then finishing your own drawing before exiting your `WM_PAINT` handler. See [Best way to call Default Drawing from a WM_PAINT message](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?48886-Best-way-to-call-Default-Drawing-from-a-WM_PAINT-message). Whether this is the right approach for you, I don't know, it is hard to tell what you are really trying to accomplish in the first place.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how best and simply I could paint the static text so that it is highlighted when mouse is hovering it. Anyways... I really appreciate your time and help. Thank you so much.

Comment: The only way to draw the text highlighted is to draw the text yourself. Which means NOT letting the control default-draw itself.  Otherwise, I would not bother with the highlighting at all, and thus not handle `WM_PAINT`. I would simply change the text's color instead, and you can do that by handling `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in the parent window, using the hover activity to dictate which color to use, and then invalidating the control to trigger a repaint whenever the color needs to be changed. I have updated my answer with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posting solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

I managed to deal with my problem on this matter.

```
//global variable(s)
COLORREF bkgndColor;
COLORREF txtColor;
HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = nullptr;
const UINT APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC = WM_APP + 1;

//class for mouse event
class MouseTrackEvents
{
    bool m_bMouseTracking;

public:
    MouseTrackEvents() : m_bMouseTracking(false) {}

    void OnMouseMove(HWND hwnd)
    {
        if (!m_bMouseTracking)
        {
            // Enable mouse tracking.
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
            tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
            tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            tme.dwHoverTime = 10; //1ms
            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            m_bMouseTracking = true;
        }
    }
    void Reset(HWND hwnd)
    {
        m_bMouseTracking = false;
    }
};

//proc for static text contorl subclass
LRESULT CALLBACK OwnerTxtProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    //local mouse track variable
    MouseTrackEvents mouseTrack;

    RECT txtRt;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &txtRt);

    POINT txtPt;
    GetCursorPos(&txtPt);

    switch (uMsg) {
        
        //...some other codes...

        case WM_NCDESTROY: {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, OwnerTxtProc, uIdSubclass);
            if (hbrBkgnd) {
                DeleteBrush(hbrBkgnd);
                hbrBkgnd = NULL;
            }

            mouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            mouseTrack.OnMouseMove(hWnd); //activate mouse tracking

            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEHOVER: {
            if (PtInRect(&txtRt, txtPt)) {
                OutputDebugString(L"--------------This text control is being hovered---------------\n");
                bkgndColor = RGB(0, 0, 200); // blue
                txtColor = RGB(200, 0, 0); // red
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            }
            else {
                OutputDebugString(L"--------------This text control is being left---------------\n");
                bkgndColor = RGB(100, 0, 0); // red bg
                txtColor = RGB(0, 100, 0); // green txt
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            }

            mouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);

            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSELEAVE: {
            if (!(PtInRect(&txtRt, txtPt))) {
                OutputDebugString(L"--------------This text control is being hovered---------------\n");
                bkgndColor = RGB(100, 0, 0); // red bg
                txtColor = RGB(0, 100, 0); // green txt
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
            }

            mouseTrack.Reset(hWnd);

            break;
        }

        case APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
            HDC hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);

            SetTextColor(hdc, txtColor);
            SetBkColor(hdc, bkgndColor);

            if (hbrBkgnd) {
                DeleteBrush(hbrBkgnd);
            }
            hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(bkgndColor);

            //return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT&>(bkgndColor); //--> error --> so i added '&'
            return (LRESULT)hbrBkgnd;
        }

        //...some other codes...
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

//parent of static text control
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //...some other codes...

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        return SendMessage(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam), APP_CTLCOLORSTATIC, wParam, 0);
    }

    case WM_CREATE: //put all sorts of stuff when the context menu is called
    {
        //font to be set to
        hFont = CreateFont(17, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Segoe UI"));

        //set font of the textCtrl
        //doesnt work if handler target = hChild
        for (int i = 0; i < textCtrlSize; i++) {
            SendMessage(textCtrl[i], WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
        }

        bkgndColor = RGB(100, 0, 0); // red bg
        txtColor = RGB(0, 100, 0); // green txt

        txtHwnd = CreateWindow(L"Static", L"Hello World!", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOTIFY, 100, 100, 120, 30, hChild, (HMENU)testingTxtID, nullptr, nullptr);
        SetWindowSubclass(txtHwnd, OwnerTxtProc, 0, 0);

        break;
    }

    //...some other codes...

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hChild, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```